# How to replace multiple occurrences of string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, liferay

I have created websites with reactjs. For restAPI's i used java and CMS is liferay. In liferay i had created the shortcode for accordion like

`('[accordion][acc-header]Heading 1[/acc-header][acc-content]Content1[/acc-content][acc-header]Heading 2[/acc-header][acc-content]Content2[/acc-content][/accordion]')`.

I want to replace html elements instead of this strings. How to do in javascript?

Here you go,

```
[accordion]
 [acc-header]Heading 1[/acc-header][acc-content]Content1[/acc-content]
 [acc-header]Heading 2[/acc-header][acc-content]Content2[/acc-content]     
[/accordion]
```

Html output,

```
<div class="accordion">
  <h3>Heading1</h3>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    content 1
  </div>
<h3>Heading2</h3>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    content 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the desired HTML output?

Comment: @TomFenech, i have edited my question. can you please check now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dirty and quick way:

```
var s = '[accordion][acc-header]Heading 1[/acc-header][acc-content]Content1[/acc-content][acc-header]Heading 2[/acc-header][acc-content]Content2[/acc-content][/accordion]';
s.replace(/\[([a-z\-]+)]/g, '<div class="$1">').replace(/\[\/[a-z\-]*]/g, '</div>')
```

The result is:

```
"<div class="accordion"><div class="acc-header">Heading 1</div><div class="acc-content">Content1</div><div class="acc-header">Heading 2</div><div class="acc-content">Content2</div></div>"
```

This won't add `<h3>` tags

Comment: That's unfair =) added an edit, but that's not a complete solve